# Modelica "derivative" annotation problem

Tags: openmodelica

I have questions about the use of "derivative" annotation I wanted to ask you. Lets put a sample.

The equation is this:

```
z_level = LevelZ(time);
```

where LevelZ(time) is an external C function, and there are also LevelZ_der(time) and LevelZ_der2(time) that are the first and second derivative.

It the code is like this, it works well...

```
function LevelZ_der2 
    input Real t; 
    input Real dt; 
    input Real ddt; 
    output Real res; 
external 
    res = LevelZ_der2(t); 
annotation(Library="...", Include="...");  
end LevelZ_der2; 

function LevelZ_der 
    input Real t 
    input Real dt 
    output Real res; 
external 
    res = LevelZ_der(t); 
annotation(derivative=LevelZ_der2, 
           Library="...", Include="...");  
end LevelZ_der; 

function LevelZ 
    input Real t 
    output Real res; 
external 
    res = LevelZ(t) 
annotation(derivative=LevelZ_der, 
           derivative(order=2)=LevelZ_der2, 
           Library="...", Include="...");  
end LevelZ;
```

... although these errors appear:

```
[C:/Users/Model/Model.mo:52:2-52:28:writable] Warning: Unused input variable dt in function .LevelZ_der2. 
[C:/Users/Model/Model.mo:52:2-52:28:writable] Warning: Unused input variable ddt in function .LevelZ_der2. 
[C:/Users/Model/Model.mo:52:2-52:28:writable] Warning: Unused input variable dt in function .LevelZ_der. 

Error: Derivative of expression 
Differentiate.differentiateExpSolve failed for z_level - LevelZ(time) 
is non-existent.
```

However if the code is like this, OpenModelica simulation ignores the derivatives...

```
function LevelZ_der2 
    input Real t; 
    output Real res; 
external 
    res = LevelZ_der2(t); 
annotation(Library="...", Include="...");  
end LevelZ_der2; 

function LevelZ_der 
    input Real t 
    output Real res; 
external 
    res = LevelZ_der(t); 
annotation(derivative(zeroDerivative=t)=LevelZ_der2, 
           Library="...", Include="...");  
end LevelZ_der; 

function LevelZ 
    input Real t 
    output Real res; 
external 
    res = LevelZ(t) 
annotation(derivative(zeroDerivative=t)=LevelZ_der,  
           derivative(order=2)=LevelZ_der2, 
           Library="...", Include="...");  
end LevelZ;
```

... and this error appear:

```
Error: Derivative of expression 
Differentiate.differentiateExpSolve failed for z_level - LevelZ(time) 
is non-existent.
```

What is the right way to do it and why?

Best regards
Koldo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `derivative(order=2)=LevelZ_der2,` from the derivative-annotation of `LevelZ` and replace the derivative annotation of `LevelZ_der` with `derivative(order=2)=LevelZ_der2`.

See Section 12.7.1 "Using the Derivative Annotation" of the [Modelica specification Version 3.3](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33.pdf).

It is a problem of the tool if the external functions are not accepted after this correction.

Comment: Thank you Tobias. Equations work properly with your advice. However error and warning messages remain.

Comment: If you did not make any other error then the error and warning messages are a problem of the tool -- and maybe, you should report it.

Comment: I have reported it in the Forum but I have not received any answer. However I will report it to the bug tracker.